# Crosspost Wordpress blog post to blogger

Tags: wordpress

I want to publish the same post which I just published in the worpress blog to blogger & facebook automaticaly. I know it possible and there are various plugin out there. But cant find one free to use plugin which do this.

I used a 'network publisher' plugin. Its free for facebook by need to pay if we want to add another on like blogger or other. But its working good for me in facebook

Now I am really worried what to do for my blogger to get automatically posted from wordpress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At last I got the blogger (.blogspot) to get my post automatically from the wordpress.

The blogger can be configured to post via email. There in the blogger account we have to create a secret email address in the setting tab

format look like this  -  name_of_the_site.secretcode@blogger.com (so that a mail send to this address will automatically posted in the blogger)

And then in the wordpress install a plugin named CROSSPRESS which do all the required stuff
where simply put the email address and the signature which we want to show underneath each post.

Test it by creating a new post and publishing it. You will get the same in blogger

DONE......

Answer (score 1):

It is now possible to post directly using Blogger API (since 4 weeks)
I think you just have to wait a plugin that integrate this feature.

Here is the API announcement : http://code.blogger.com/2012/06/blogger-api-v3.html

Answer (score 0):

Simply set up Blogger and Facebook to get your Wordpress site RSS feed. Look at Blogger and Facebook for docs on how to do that.

Comment: sorry, It would not work because I want the wordpress blog post to come in the blogger(.blogspot) as usual post.

Answer (score 0):

Cross post seems to have issues in that line breaks don't get carried across properly and it seems to generate ASCII character 160 in a few random places as well at the moment.